# Maintain the access control authorization on a Cloud SQL replica on failover?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We're using Google CloudSQL 2nd generation and have configured the primary to be available only from certain networks using the "Access Control" features.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/high-availability) says:

> When a zonal outage occurs and your master fails over to your failover replica, any existing connections to the instance are closed. However, your application can reconnect using the same connection string or IP address; you do not need to update your application after a failover.

Does this also imply that we don't have to maintain the access control list on the replica as well? Or do we have to maintain this on both the replica and on the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make sure the ACLs are in sync with the master and the failover replica. This is not done automatically (for now).

Comment: Sorry, so does this mean every time I add an authorized network (IP address) to the Access Control on my Master I have to add it to the Failover instance as well?